# Basic foreach loop question

Tags: php, foreach

Thanks for the help here:

[foreach loops & stdclass objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744128/foreach-loops-stdclass-objects)

I set up a foreach loop, but the problem is that sometimes the result is:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for
>   foreach() in
>   /home/MYACCOUNT/public_html/the
>   script.php on line 81

I think that's when there is nothing to fill the foreach loop but got scared that this was happening when there was indeed one entry.

My question is: what does a foreach loop do when there is only one entry?

Comment: A bit of the actual code may help in answering specifically .

Comment: Please show some code (especially the code around the relevant line that generates your warning).

Comment: Make sure you pass to an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`foreach` only works on arrays, so you'll need to wrap that one element in an array.

> As of PHP 5, it is possible to iterate objects too. 
>   http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

To learn more about iterating over objects see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php

Comment: In php5 objects can be iterated.

Comment: @Tim Lytle: if that object is the object that should be part of the array that is being looped over, looping over the object and over the array are two different things.

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php for more information.

Comment: @koen Yes, but the statement is incorrect and misleading regardless. Since the original question (linked at the top) was using objects, it seems relevant to point out.

Comment: @Tim Lytle: you are right. It's not about the RealTimeCommissionDataV2 => array in the original post.

Comment: how do I wrap it in an array?

Comment: To wrap a variable in an array you just need: array($var);

Answer (score 3):

`foreach` in [PHP5 can iterate over an object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php), or an Array.

*I post this to balance those telling you that you can't use an object.*

And as the other answers cover, if your data will be iterated in a `foreach`, it must be wrapped the same every time. Always an array (even if it's only one element), or always an object (even if it's only one method).

Answer (score 2):

Like oremj says you will need an array. If you sometimes have an array and sometimes only one thing you can cast it to an array to make sure you're working with arrays every time. The one thing will be array('the one thing') after casting it to an array. Then you can loop over it and the loop will start and end with 'the one thing'.

edit: as others have pointed out looping over an object is possible also.

Comment: How do I cast it to an array?

Comment: @pg something like: `foreach ( (array) $yourArray as $key => $val)`

Answer (score 1):

foreach will work just fine on an array containing only 1 element.  Try this example:

```
$foodlist = array("burrito");

foreach ($foodlist as $food) {
  echo $food . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An example:

```
<?php

$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
foreach ($array as $value) {
    echo $value."<br />";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Make sure array is an array
if (!$array) $array = array();
if (!is_array($array)) $array = array($array);

foreach ($array as $value) {
    echo $value."<br />";
}
```